# Multi image upload

Tags: php, image-uploading

I'm learning PHP and can not find a way to make this work. Did I write correct code to upload multiple images?

I can not think of a reason why this should be wrong.

```
$imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image, drie1, drie2, drie3, add, strip"]["name"]);    
$imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));    
$imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image, drie1, drie2, drie3, add, strip"]["type"]);
```

Comment: Why not test it then?

Comment: Have a look on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Send these files:<br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
</form>
```

**PHP**  (*file-upload.php*)

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

This will display the info of the uploaded files

You can add `accept` attribute to the input to limit the allowed filetypes by extention

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="image_file[]" multiple=""> /* multiple tag is used to upload multiple files */
     <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Php**

```
<?php
foreach($_FILES["image_file"]["name"] as $key => $value)
{
    $name = $value;
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["image_file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    $type = $_FILES["image_file"]["type"][$key];

    echo $name." , ".$tmp_name." , ".$type."\n";
}
?>
```